# Open page in Joomla

Tags: php, html, joomla

I'm using Jumi to echo php code and then showing that in a Joomla Article, and everythings working fine. Now I want to do this:

The output is basically a list from a database like this:

```
Name    Price    Type
A       1        T1
B       2        T2
```

In this list I want to include links to only show items of the same type, so "T1" would like to a page only showing things of type T1. So I thought I would do this by making a new page that takes a type and then get all the items of that type from the database. Without Joomla this wouldv'e been a piece of cake, with Joomla I'm not quite sure where to begin.

How should the a href=... tags in the html code printed by my php script look?
Is my basic structure still correct, and if so, how do I make Joomla open the new page in the normal frame and not replace the whole Joomla page. some kind of target-frame attribute?

EDIT:
I know I should be using a component instead, however I just need to get this working before going on vacation in three days. I will do it properly when I get back. 
I don't mind if the entire page reloads, what I do need is the Joomla menu, header-banner and other things around the page to be loaded as well. If I just use a href=mypage.php I assume the header and everything around it will disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going about this all wrong. You shouldn't be using Jumi to run php in your articles. You should design a component. Although this will take a tiny bit longer to setup initially it will save you time in the long run and prove to be much more flexible than using Jumi in a single article. Have a look here on how to create a Joomla component - http://www.joomladevuser.com/tutorials/components.

a href= tags should not be any different from any other html you have ever used.

E.g. `echo '<a href="http://.....">link</a>';`

To make just the frame/div/table/etc reload rather than the entire page you will need to implement some AJAX. I have answered a question on how to do this with Joomla components before, see here: [how to use Jquery AJAX in Joomla Components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157488/how-to-use-jquery-ajax-in-joomla-components)

Comment: Yes I know I should be using a component, unfortunately I only got three days to do this before going on vacation, so it became a ugly hack and then I'm doing this properly once I get back in two months. Thanks for the tip though, will look into the AJAX.