# Custom fields in Joomla 2.5 registration form

Tags: forms, joomla

I want to include Country, State, City dropdown option in my Joomla Registration form. How can I add these fields?? Also I want these to be **dependent Dropdown**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you google? Let me do that for you

Joomla 2.5 & 3.0 have follow the same procedure of implementing custom registration form.

[Adding custom field in default joomla 3.1.1 registration form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336842/adding-custom-field-in-default-joomla-3-1-1-registration-form)

[Joomla! 3: how to add custom fields to user registration form](http://library.logicsistemi.it/en/joomla/general-topics/93-joomla-3-custom-fields-for-user-s-profile)

[Joomla 3.1.1 Adding custom fields in user registration](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=803465)

[Creating a profile plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin)

Comment: I want dependent dropdown.

Comment: How to use ajax.. I don't know how implement ajax in Joomla.. I know the normal way where I call javascript from the form element, but I have no idea how to do it Joomla 2.5 Can yo please help???

Comment: Use controller actions

Comment: Google 1st next time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157488/how-to-use-jquery-ajax-in-joomla-components